# Change line color in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

How do I set the color of a line in Plotly?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, subplot_titles=('Plot 1', 'Plot 2'))

# plot the first line of the first plot
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=self.x_axis_pd, y=self.y_1, mode='lines+markers', name='line#1'), row=1, col=1)  # this line should be #ffe476
```

I tried `fillcolor`, but I suspect that doesn't work because this is a simple line.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can add `line=dict(color="#ffe476")` inside your `go.Scatter(...)` call. Documentation here: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter-line-color

Answer (score 48):

@nicolaskruchten is of course right, but I'd like to throw in two other options:

```
line_color="#0000ff"
```

And:

```
 fig['data'][0]['line']['color']="#00ff00"
```

Or:

```
 fig.data[0].line.color = "#00ff00"
```

I particularly appreciate the flexibility of the latter option since it easily lets you set a new color for a desired line **after** you've built a figure using for example `fig.append_trace(go.Scatter())` or `fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter))`. Below is an example using all three options.

**Code 1:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.cos(t)
y2= np.sin(t)
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=t, y=y,mode='lines+markers', line_color='#ffe476'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=t, y=y2,mode='lines+markers', line=dict(color="#0000ff")))
fig.show()
```

**Plot 1:**

[image]

Now you can change the colors directly if you insert the snippet below in a new cell and run it.

**Code 2:**

```
fig['data'][0]['line']['color']="#00ff00"
fig.show()
```

**Plot 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter(
                    x=list(dict_val['yolo_timecost'].keys()),
                    y=signal.savgol_filter(list(dict_val['yolo_timecost'].values()),2653,3),
                    mode='lines',
                    name='YOLOv3实时耗时',
                    line=dict(
                        color='rgb(204, 204, 204)',
                        width=5
                    ),
                    ),
                )
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @yujiang I see you are referring to a data sample that does not exist. It would probably be better to provide a complete suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```py
fig.data[0].line.color = 'rgb(204, 20, 204)'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use color_discrete_sequence like that

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada',color_discrete_sequence=["#ff97ff"])
fig.show()
```