# Graph line color in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly

There are two lines in the chart. Axis X-time, axis Y-depth of immersion. Depending on the time, a certain phase of work takes place. How to color the line for each phase in plotly? I didn’t find anything similar for the lines in the documentation, only for points.

```
# well_a_data.RelatedPhase
# well_b_data.RelatedPhase

well_a_trace = go.Scatter(
    x = well_a_data.Days,
    y = well_a_data.HoleDepth,
    mode = 'lines',
    name = well_a_name
)
well_b_trace = go.Scatter(
    x = well_b_data.Days,
    y = well_b_data.HoleDepth,
    mode = 'lines',
    name = well_b_name
)
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert `line=dict(color="#00ff00")` inside `go.Scatter`.

You can also use `fig['data'][0]['line']['color']="#00ff00"`, or any other [hex color code](https://www.color-hex.com/).

This has been described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188816/plotly-set-line-color/58191545#58191545).